# Change selected value programmatically in React class based component

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, react-class-based-component

I am using a React class based component and material UI to display the dropdown. I am originally setting a default value and the select dropdown values get changed according to user click. However, I want to change the values programmatically, for eg. - I want to do something like I change the value in a variable, eg - age=40, and the dropdown which earlier had age=30 choses, now automatically reflects the value 40. Can anyone suggest please?

I tried passing value={this.age} in the  option. And changed the value of this.age to 40 somewhere in the code programatically, however the drop-down still displays the value 30 for me

Comment: Are you storing `age` in `this.state`, and updating it via `this.setState`?

Comment: Yes I tried via this.state.age and this.setState{age:40} in the undo event but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `<select>`, the straightforward answer is:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      age: "10"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ age: "40" })}>
          Set age to 40
        </button>
        <p>A dropdown:</p>
        <select
          value={this.state.value}
          onClick={(e) => this.setState({ age: e.target.value })}
        >
          <option value="10" selected={this.state.age === "10"}>10</option>
          <option value="20" selected={this.state.age === "20"}>20</option>
          <option value="30" selected={this.state.age === "30"}>30</option>
          <option value="40" selected={this.state.age === "40"}>40</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you click on the button, the selection will change.

Comment: I will not be clicking the button. Maybe some other event, let's say 'Undo' selection or some other event - and the value in the dropdown field needs to reflect the older value without the user clicking on the selection.

Comment: @user13569341 Button click event is just a way to show how programmatic change works. You can use any event.